# Why are certain SoundCloud API tracks non-streamable despite the metadata indicating otherwise?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, soundcloud

I'm developing a SoundCloud app for Android this year and I've just come across a problem for the second time this year that has left me scratching my head.

Certain tracks depsite being listed as:
streamable: true
sharing: public

Simply won't stream. This applies to BOTH pasting the url in a browser or attempting to stream with the Android mediaplayer.

It seems to apply to all tracks with a labelname attribute of: "Interscope Records" 
It also seems to apply to all tracks where user = "elliegoulding"

Here is one example you can test for yourself.

salient metadata attributes as follows:

- 1. streamable: true
  2. sharing: public
  3. user->permalink->elliegoulding
  4. title - Ellie Goulding - Goodness Gracious (The Chainsmokers remix)
  5. stream_url - https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/130459845/stream?client_id=

Again this is all Ellie Goulding tracks that have user->permalink->elliegoulding

The problem is I need to filter these out of my search results to avoid users becoming frustrated. With the Android mediaplayer it triggers the errorlistener callback with an error code of -38.

If I paste the stream_url?client_id=validclientid the browser just balks.

With a good url the browser will play the track simply by pasting in the url+client_id. And obviously the mediaplayer for android will work its magic as well.

What I've done for Interscope records was to add a filter to remove all their content from API search results. I guess I will do that for Ellie Goulding but this is simply an inelegant, albeit necessary hack since the metadata is misleading.

I do not want to reply upon the mediaplayer errorhandler as that bleeds into the app's user experience by taking up time and showing tracks beginning to load then skipping due to the aforementioned issue.

BTW these tracks all play on my webapp which uses your awesome HTML5 player widget. It seems there is a definite disconnect somewhere since they do not play from a URL.

At any rate I thank you for your awesome public API and I do hope you can hopefully offer a metadata hook to filtrate this category of tracks thereby eliminating a source of frustration to my beta users.

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: What "original format" does this track have? "wav"?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!! I definitely remember one was ".aiff".

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my app, seems like it's a problem which SoundCloud is going to fix soon (let's hope so).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this track (http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/147078202.json?client_id=apigee) and all the tracks from Century Media. Any news? Is it a bug?